# IE versus Firefox in displaying anchor color

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, anchor

I just notice a very odd behaviour in Firefox 3.5. I am running Firefox 3.5 under Ubuntu Jaunty Jackalope (9.04) and Windows XP.

When I open the following URL : http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_link2

Firefox renders the links in blue. When I open it with IE 6.0 it shows the links in 'red'.

According to the style sheet that the site uses:

```
<style type="text/css">
a.one:link {color: #ff0000}
a.one:visited {color: #0000ff}
a.one:hover {color: #ffcc00}

a.two:link {color: #ff0000}
a.two:visited {color: #0000ff}
a.two:hover {font-size: 150%}

a.three:link {color: #ff0000}
a.three:visited {color: #0000ff}
a.three:hover {background: #66ff66}

a.four:link {color: #ff0000}
a.four:visited {color: #0000ff}
a.four:hover {font-family: monospace}

a.five:link {color: #ff0000; text-decoration: none}
a.five:visited {color: #0000ff; text-decoration: none}
a.five:hover {text-decoration: underline}
</style>
```

These links should be displayed in 'red' (#ff0000). Is this a bug in firefox, or is this how the browser should renders the anchor according to the W3C standard ?

Cheers,

Comment: Well, have you visited the URLs that the links are pointing to in one browser but not the other?

Comment: Nope i have not visited any of the links.

Answer (score 2):

Try clearing your browser cache. Its in your history. If you change the `:visited` part to a different color, you will see the difference.

Comment: Nope tried that. Still the same behaviour. Firefox shows the links as 'Blue' not 'Red'

Comment: agreed, if you have visited the links in your browser before, they will appear blue #0000ff;

Comment: just tried in Firefox 3.5.3/Win XP. They start red, if visited they appear blue. If I delete the visited page from my history and reload, they're back to red.

Comment: Thanks, brism, i shall try firefox 3.5.3 =D